# Get frame of an UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, frame, uibarbuttonitem, uipopover

I have created an UIBarButtonItem inside a NavigationBar:

```
UIBarButtonItem *filtroFecha = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch target:self action:@selector(filtrarFecha:)]autorelease];


    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: addActivity, filtroFecha, nil];
```

Now I want to open a popover from this button, but I am not able to get the frame of the UIBarButtonItem.

```
if (_filtroActividadesView == nil) {
        self.filtroActividadesView = [[CRMFiltroActividadViewController alloc] init];
        _filtroActividadesView.delegate = self;
        self.filtroPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] 
                                  initWithContentViewController:_filtroActividadesView];               
    }

    [self.filtroPopover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1400, 44) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:permittedArrowDirections:animated:`.

```
[self.filtroPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:filtroFecha
                    permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                    animated:YES];
```

Comment: Beat me to it, while I was off getting the [relevant URL](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html).